# R adding a column based on the value of another column

Tags: r, addition, reshape

I am trying to convert a data.frame that has data like this

```
COMPANY COUNTRY CURRENCY IND1     WGT1 IND2   WGT2 IND3     WGT3
COMP1   USA     USD      HEALTH   .58  RETAIL .42  <NA>     0
COMP2   USA     USD      AUTO     .78  RETAIL .12  TRANSPRT .1
COMP3   CAN     CAD      SOFTWARE 1    <NA>   0    <NA>     0
```

I want to transform this into

```
COMPANY COUNTRY CURRENCY HEALTH AUTO SOFTWARE RETAIL TRANSPRT
COMP1   USA     USD      .58    0    0        .42    0
COMP2   USA     USD      0      .78  0        .12    .1
COMP3   CAN     CAD      0      0    1        0      0
```

What is the best way to approach this?
Thanks in advance
BE

Answer (score 2):

We can use `melt/dcast` from the  `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5`.

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  The `melt` from `data.table` can take multiple `measure` columns.  We specify the column names that start with prefix 'IND', 'WGT' as `patterns`, and convert the 'wide' to 'long' format.  Remove the 'variable' column by assigning it to NULL, and then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' specifying the 'value.var' as 'value2'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT <- melt(setDT(df1), measure=patterns('^IND', 'WGT'),
                            na.rm=TRUE)[, variable:=NULL]
dcast(DT, ...~value1, value.var='value2', fill=0)
#   COMPANY COUNTRY CURRENCY AUTO HEALTH RETAIL SOFTWARE TRANSPRT
#1:   COMP1     USA      USD 0.00   0.58   0.42        0      0.0
#2:   COMP2     USA      USD 0.78   0.00   0.12        0      0.1
#3:   COMP3     CAN      CAD 0.00   0.00   0.00        1      0.0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COMPANY = c("COMP1", "COMP2", "COMP3"), 
COUNTRY = c("USA", 
"USA", "CAN"), CURRENCY = c("USD", "USD", "CAD"), IND1 = c("HEALTH", 
"AUTO", "SOFTWARE"), WGT1 = c(0.58, 0.78, 1), IND2 = c("RETAIL", 
"RETAIL", NA), WGT2 = c(0.42, 0.12, 0), IND3 = c(NA, "TRANSPRT", 
NA), WGT3 = c(0, 0.1, 0)), .Names = c("COMPANY", "COUNTRY", "CURRENCY", 
"IND1", "WGT1", "IND2", "WGT2", "IND3", "WGT3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This works but I can't really use a development version of data.table in our production. I will use the reshape option given by Webb with dcast instead of xtabs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a default libraries solution using `reshape` and `xtabs`

```
long<-reshape(df,sep="",varying=4:9,direction="long")
cbind(df[,1:3],as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(WGT~COMPANY+IND,long)))
```

```
      COMPANY COUNTRY CURRENCY AUTO HEALTH SOFTWARE RETAIL TRANSPRT
COMP1   COMP1     USA      USD 0.00   0.58        0   0.42      0.0
COMP2   COMP2     USA      USD 0.78   0.00        0   0.12      0.1
COMP3   COMP3     CAN      CAD 0.00   0.00        1   0.00      0.0
```

Comment: I use dcast instead of xtabs and got this working. Here is what I did. 
library(reshape2)
df.long<-reshape(df,sep="",varying=c(4:9),direction="long") 
df.long$id <- df.long$time <- NULL 
dcast(df.long[!is.na(df.long$IND),], ...~IND,value.var='WGT',fill=0)